# running 64bit exe outside of c:\program files\

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

i have a 64bit windows7 and i want to run a 64bit executable which is not inside the c:\Program Files\ directory. 
i always get the error:

```
The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.
```

i think this is because the OS treats it as 32bit although it is 64bit.

how can i still run this executable?

Comment: some more information would be cool, have you written the programm by yourself? I had a similar error once with a programm written in vs2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely not an issue of the application not residing in the `\Program Files\` folder, but is actually a missing library.  Windows can detect whether the executable is 32-bit or 64-bit regardless of where the application is in the folder structure.

I see this error often when the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime has not been installed correctly.  Where did this application come from?  I would suggest contacting the original developer for support.  You may also try downloading the [latest version of the runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=BD512D9E-43C8-4655-81BF-9350143D5867&displaylang=en) from Microsoft to see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied the exe from c:\programe files\, then you have to copy all other files and folders within the same folder. After that you may run it if you are lucky.